# How to mark touch event listeners as passive in flutter-web?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

I want to use passive listeners to improve scrolling performance of my flutter web-app. Is there a way to mark the touch and wheel event listeners as `passive` to improve the page's scroll performance?

Comment: Any update on this?

Comment: Nope, I was not able to find any resolution for it